# Ubuntu keeps asking me to install after restart (hard disk install)

Tags: system-installation, unetbootin

I'm new to this so i don't know what to do. I installed ubuntu using Hard disk installation on Unetbootin after watching a video on Youtube. Everything works fine but it keeps asking me the same thing (Try/Install ubuntu) after restart.

Comment: unplug your usb/device containing the iso or boot files for ubuntu. That might help

Comment: @JAMSHAID i used hard disk installation so i don't have anything plugged in

Comment: You should be specific with details for us to best understand. Ubuntu is available with multiple ISOs for download & install; with *five* installers available... You've not said which you used only mentioning a non-installer but *live* ISO writer that will ask you to install as it's not an installer (installers are `ubiquity`, `subiquity`, `calamares`, *debian installer*, *canary*.. not unetbootin)

Comment: I dont know the details but i've used Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS that i downloaded on the site

Comment: I managed to make it work! removing my other hdd did the trick. it seems like the left over files from my windows 10 were the problem.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Desktop default ISO uses `ubiquity` as installer, Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Server uses `subiquity`, there maybe *alternate* ISOs too though not easily found using *canary*... but you've not said which you used.  Specific details help

Comment: I used the desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the other HDD solved the problem. Startup Disk Creator works much better than UNetbootin, and it can be used to install other Linux distributions besides just Ubuntu. To avoid encountering the same problem in the future use Rufus or the built-in Startup Disk Creator application instead of UNetbootin to make a bootable Ubuntu installation USB.